# I need the biggest Date from current year in PHP from an Date Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need the biggest date from current year.

I have an date array as :

```
$dateArray = array('2019-05-12','2019-04-02','2020-01-07','2019-11-10','2020-07-13','2019-08-15');
```

As current year is `2019` so I need the value `2019-11-10` as my result.

Comment: why not just .. sort the array and take the first one?

Comment: ^ and filter the year before

Comment: @treyBake it will not work as it will gives us biggest one from the array while I need biggest value from current year only

Comment: @MagentoDev but surely biggest year = current year? o.O

Comment: @splash58 can you plz give your ans

Comment: Have you done any coding yourself yet to solve this?

Comment: @treyBake No as you can see in my question i have 2020 as well

Comment: @MagentoDev ah I see - in which case filter out this year from the array and sort.

Comment: @Magento asking a question is not meant to _replace_ doing your own research, it is something that you do **after** you research exhaustively and try to self-solve.

Answer (score 0):

First filter the current year by using `array_filter` then use `max`

```
 $dateArray = array_filter($dateArray, function($v){return strpos($v, date('Y')) !== false ? $v : '';});
 echo max($dateArray);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/eONDq

Comment: You must add the filter for current year too.

Comment: @ErwinMoller Noted and updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = max(array_map('strtotime', $arr));
echo date('Y-m-j H:i:s', $max);
```